# (PHP) MySQL random rows big table with order by and certain range

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have this table:

```
person_id int(10) pk
fid bigint(20) unique
points int(6) index
birthday date index
4 FK columns int(6)
ENGINE = MyISAM
```

**Important info:** the table contains over 8 million rows and is fast growing (1.5M a day at the moment)

**What I want:** to select 4 random rows in a certain range when I order the table on points

**How I do it now:** In PHP I randomize a certain range, let's say this gives me 20% as low range and 30% as high range. Next I count(*) the number of rows in table. After I determine the lowest row number: table count / 100 * low range. Same for high range. After I calculate a random row by using rand(lowest_row, highest_row), which gives me a row number within the range. And at last I select the random row by doing:

```
SELECT * FROM `persons` WHERE points > 0 ORDER BY points desc LIMIT $random_offset, 1;
```

The points > 0 is in the query since I only want randoms with at least 1 point.

Above query takes about 1.5 seconds to run, but since I need 4 rows it takes over 6 seconds, which is too slow for me. I figured the order by points takes the most time, so I was thinking about making a VIEW of the table, but I have really no experience with views, so what do you think? Is a view a good option or are there better solutions?

**ADDED:**

I forgot to say that it is important that all rows has the same chance of being selected.

Thanks, I appreciate all the help! :)

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is so slow, and will become exponentially slower, because using `LIMIT` here forces it to do a full table sort, and then a full table scan, to get the result. Instead you should do this on the PHP end of things as well (this kind of 'abuse' of `LIMIT` is actually the reason it's non-standard SQL and for example MSSQL and Oracle do not support it).

First ensure there's an index on `points`. This will make `select max(points), min(points) from persons` a query that'll return instantly. Next you can determine from those 2 results the points range, and use `rand()` to determine 4 points in the requested range. Then repeat for each result:

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE points < $myValue ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 1
```

Since it only has to retrieve one row, and can determine which one via the index, this'll be in the milliseconds execution time as well.

Comment: And if he can determine the 4 points after the max/min query, then he could use a single query with "WHERE points IN($rand_pt1,$rand_pt2,$rand_pt3,$rand_pt4)"?

Comment: Well that might work if there's a full distribution of points. It is however very well possible that randomizing in PHP might yield scores that are not present in the database, as such using `IN` syntax might not yield 4 results (or even none at all). That's why I offered the `< ... LIMIT 1` construct instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but I do not fully understand it yet. You are selecting min points and max points as range, but I would need a range which depends on row counter I think, or could it work with points too? As example I want 4 random rows in the top 10% of the table when it is ordered on points.

Comment: It's not practically feasible to randomize on the row count, except if it's a never-delete table (you could then safely use an AI PK based on that premise). As for any kind of randomization - don't do it in the database on this kind of table size, it'll kill your MySQL in the end. Find PHP-side alternatives, and accept that they might be less precise.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Thanks again for explaining. I'm quite new to MySQL but your query will return the first row below the $myValue. In the table many rows have the same amount of points and it is very important that every row has the same chance of being selected. Sorry I should have said that before. Any way you see a solution for that?

Comment: Well no, if that's a killer criterium this solution is already invalid, since it prefers scores that do not have near neighbours in front of them (@MikeBrant's solution in the other answer is also invalid for this requirement). The only way to implement a perfect distribution (assuming there's no perfect gapless auto-increment candidate) is your own solution with `LIMIT $rownumber, 1`, and that's always going to be slow and become exponentially slower as the table grows.

Comment: Bad luck :( but will it make a difference if I create another table which will hold the points of the row at 10%, 20%, etc and use that value to select a random row which will not have the order by method but only where points < $highpoints and points > $lowpoints?

Comment: If the table is growing 1.5M rows per day that's only postponing the inevitable - at one point or another the 10% tables will also become unwieldy themselves. The only real solutions are to make your requirements for exact randomization less strict, or cache the randomized results internally so you don't have to query them all the time. The amount of data is just too much to ask a DB to do something it's very bad at - DBs are optimized for showing *exactly correct* results, not for showing randomized bits of data.

Comment: Hi Niels. I will accept your answer. Thanks for the help. At the moment i am thinking to grab rows (20 or 40) and decide in the php file which rows to show (so i can manage a little which points range is shown but of course this will not be as precise as i had before and i can only work with the rows i did get from the random function, which can be all high points or all low or some of both. The sql query will be a lot faster without the offset, right?

Comment: It's still going to be slow if you're streaming a couple million rows to PHP before deciding which handful to show  :)  You'll need some kind of caching mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Views aren't going to do anything to help your performance here.  My suggestion would be to simply run:

```
SELECT * FROM `persons` WHERE points BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Make sure you have an index on points. Also, you SHOULD replace `*` with only the fields you are concerned about if applicable.  Here is course `?` represents the upper and lower bounds for your search.

You can then determine the number of rows returned in the result set using `mysqli_num_rows()` (or similar based on your DB library of choice).

You now have the total number of rows that meet your criteria.  You can easily then calculate 4 random numbers within the range of results and use `mysqli_data_seek()` or similar to go directly to the record at the random offset and get the values you want from it.

Putting it all together:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_conn, $sql); // here $sql is your SQL query
$num_records = 4; // your number of records to return
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$rows = array();

while ($i = 0; $i < $num_records; $i++) {
   $random_offset = rand(0, $num_rows - 1);
   mysqli_data_seek($result, $random_offset);
   $rows[] = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Comment: This is not a practical solution given the table size, OP says *"the table contains over 8 million rows and is fast growing (1.5M a day at the moment)"*. Your solution will also get the DB on its knees when it has to select 100 million rows and pick some random results from that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Two questions. Are all rows unique in the rows array? Second , do you think it is possible/smart to use max(points) instead of count(*) and determine the range on points instead of row_counter. This will be much faster as you suggested but what if I create the point ranges and in a certain range there are only a few rows and in other ranges there are much more rows, than those rows will be shown more in the random function. Is there a way to somehow fix this so all rows has same change?

Comment: In my Question I forgot to say that it is very important that all rows has the same chance of being selected.